# Riddle Requiring Magical Knowledge

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

This may be too tricky (it requires specialized knowledge) or have multiple answers, but I'll try to make it specific:

> 1. My name sets afire confusion and ire.
> 2. With creatures acquired, battles change on the fly.
> 3. Bring with you your child, for it's once in awhile.
> 4. When monsters say "hi," I request a "goodbye."
> 5. When you see me it's often when I'm not on the bottom.
> 6. If you know that I'm there, you know how to prepare.

That's it! Good luck!

P.S. Thanks to @GentlePurpleRain for figuring out what rhyme scheme and meter this is!

Comment: Do the numbered clues (1-6) indicate six different sub-solutions, or are they all hints towards a single answer?

Comment: @randal'thor They're all hints toward a single answer. I numbered them to make them easier to reference. (Clue 1, Clue 2, etc)

Comment: According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry)#Feet) (as far as I understand it), this is amphibrachic tetrameter catalectic, with a rhyme scheme of AAAB CCCB DDEE.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Wow! Thanks! I'm quite impressed!

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be the MTG entity

> [Marit Lage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=416746)

My name sets afire confusion and ire.

> Based on Lovecraftian horrors, [Curse of Marit Lage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=2617) and [Wrath of Marit Lage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=45254) stymie Blue and Red, the colours of Confusion and Ire

With creatures acquired, battles change on the fly.

> It is a creature with flying, and usually wins the game when it hits the battlefield, however, it comes from the card [Dark Depths](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=416746), which plays a very different type of magic game before Marit Lage can come out.

Bring with you your child, for it's once in awhile.
When monsters say "hi," I request a "goodbye."

> I think these are both referring to a much smaller recent card that has a similar mechanic to Marit Lage, [Thing in the Ice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=409836%20Thing%20In%20The%20Ice). When the last ice counter is removed from it, it transforms to a much stronger creature (though still much weaker than Marit Lage) and returns most other creatures to their owners hands.

When you see me it's often when I'm not on the bottom.

> Marit Lage rises from the [Dark Depths](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=416746), and that's when you see her

If you know that I'm there, you know how to prepare.

> Land Destruction or forced Creature Sacrifice are ways to answer Marit Lage that decks don't always play, but certainly would if they knew they were playing against a [Dark Depths](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=416746) deck.

Comment: No, but you're suprisingly close! "Bring with you your child, for it's once in  while" is probably a good clue to focus on.

Answer (score 1):

I actually think the answer is

> Pokémon, or a game of pokémon

My name sets afire confusion and ire.

> Least sure about this clue, could be because of the accented 'é' in pokémon, which has led to confusion about the pronunciation

With creatures acquired, battles change on the fly.

> Obviously as the game progresses, you catch (acquire) more pokémon and each battle changes accordingly based on the 6 you carry

Bring with you your child, for it's once in awhile.

> Again, not sure about this one, possibly referring to Pikachu, Ash's "child" in the original series

When monsters say "hi," I request a "goodbye."

> In most games, when you encounter a random pokémon in the wild, you run from it to save time

When you see me it's often when I'm not on the bottom.

> Speculation: In classic pokémon battles in the game, the wild pokémon is on the top side of the screen and the trainer and his pokémon are on the bottom side

If you know that I'm there, you know how to prepare.

> In the games, if you know you'll be facing wild pokémon a lot, you'll bring "Repel" (or Super, or Max) thus being 'prepared'

Its a long shot :)

Comment: From the title, I suspect this has to do with Magic: The Gathering instead, and I suspect it refers to a specific card. Alas, I have very little knowledge of the game, and can't hope to determine which one.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain if it's a M:TG card, then the last line suggests the card can be "tutored" (specifically searched for and drawn using another card). I'd guess that would be as good a place as any to start, as tutoring is a relatively uncommon effect

Comment: @GentilePurpleRain I've been thinking along similar lines, and though I've been playing for probably close to 20 years now clues 1, 2, 5, and 6 make me think of quite a few cards.  Finding something to fit 3 and 4 will be a little more challenging though.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Child Of Alara?

My name sets afire confusion and ire

> It's a heavy hitter and has strong consequences when destroyed

With creatures acquired, battles change on the fly.

> It's a creature that turns the tide of battle

Bring with you your child, for it's once in awhile.

> May be a reference to its name

When monsters say "hi," I request a "goodbye."

> If you destroy it with creatures, you basically clear the table

When you see me it's often when I'm not on the bottom.

> It's expensive and 5 colored mana so normally you have to be on top (winning) to cast it.

If you know that I'm there, you know how to prepare.

> You can Sidedeck properly with cards that don't destroy but rather send him to the bottom of your opponent's deck or maybe exile it (IF you know he's there).

Comment: Honestly, it's been a while and I don't remember what the answer is. I'll see if it's on my computer somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are:

> A necromancer, or a specific Ulysses?

My name sets afire confusion and ire.

> Many medieval writers believed that resurrection required the assistance of the Christian God. They saw the practice of divination as conjuring demons who took the appearance of spirits. The practice became known explicitly as "demonic magic", and the Catholic Church condemned it.
>  People shivered when they heard of Necromancers.

With creatures acquired, battles change on the fly.

> Necromancy is a supposed practice of magic involving communication with >! the deceased – either by summoning their spirit as an apparition or >! raising them bodily. 
>  In Guild Wars, they were able to summon creatures, which would make you >! win fights.

Bring with you your child, for it's once in awhile.

> In Guild Wars, they were able to summon creatures, which would make you win fights. Which was for a while... for like 5 minutes for example. Then it would despawn.

When monsters say "hi," I request a "goodbye."

> When the summoned monsters great live, I say goodbye to my enemy.

When you see me it's often when I'm not on the bottom.

> Unsure about this.

If you know that I'm there, you know how to prepare.

> In the present day, necromancy is more generally used as a term to describe the pretense of manipulation of death and the dead, often facilitated through the use of ritual magic or some other kind of occult ceremony. 
>  Sooo... Prepare for death?

Maybe a little bit far fetched?

Comment: Unsure about the bottom clue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> an evacuation?

My name sets afire confusion and ire.

> Seems like an evacuation.

With creatures acquired, battles change on the fly.

> Yeah,there are evacuation planes

Bring with you your child, for it's once in awhile.

> You save your child.

When monsters say "hi," I request a "goodbye."

> You run when evacuating

When you see me it's often when I'm not on the bottom.

> Everyone will evacuate if is there danger to life

If you know that I'm there, you know how to prepare

> Go through evacuation exit